CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set
I kept getting this error while trying to compile. I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019.
CMAKE Error at CMakeLista.txt
Generator
NMake MakeFiles
does not support specification, but toolset
v142
was specified.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set
I’m trying to use CMake and Conan to compile a different executable for an application that I cannot mention. I originally was using VS Code and thought not having a compiler was the issue( although I had one installed) so I went and got VS Professional 2019.

Try running CMake from a Visual Studio command prompt x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 so that the environment variables for your compiler are set.  I have the VS command prompts configured in Windows Terminal and I use them to do all of my CMake generation inside / run CMake-Gui from the command prompt with the environment settings I want set.

You will have to give us a lot more information if we are to help you here. From what you have given it us, it sounds like there is some lack of basic knowledge of how CMake works that is the problem.
